# TypeScript indexable property bag type?

Tags: typescript

Does TypeScript have a built-in type that would be equivalent to the following?

```
interface PropertyBag {
    [propName: string]: any;
}
```

It's easy enough to define, but it seems like a common enough structure that it might already exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of [TypeScript 2.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#partial-readonly-record-and-pick), `PropertyBag` above is equivalent to [`Record<string, any>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type).

> Constructs an object type whose property keys are `Keys` and whose property values are `Type`. This utility can be used to map the properties of a type to another type.

Knowing what I know now, I'd avoid `any` in favor of `unknown`. And if at all possible use a more specific type than `string` for the key.

Answer (score 1):

As of TypeScript 2.2, this type is nearly indistinguishable from `any` in most uses.

Comment: Could you go so far as to take out the  `nearly` and the `in most uses`?

Comment: As far as I can tell, `PropertyBag` rejects `number`, `string`, and `boolean`; `any` does not.